# GAE appends current url to css path thus causing 404 on files

Tags: google-app-engine, routes, google-app-engine-python

This is the route that the css path is being appended:

```
  app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/edit/([\d]+)'       ,  EditUserHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Handler:

```
class EditUserHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
       user_key = ndb.Key('User',int(user_id))
       user = user_key.get()
       self.render( 'edit.html', user)
```

app.yaml:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: builds/development/css
```

HTML(edit.html) where the handler is called:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
<a href="/edit/{{user.key.id()}}">edit</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Base HTML where CSS is referenced:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Console, the first one is the url generated, the other one is the wrong path:

```
GET /edit/5908775487668224 HTTP/1.1 200 2917
GET /edit/css/main.css HTTP/1.1 404 154
```

The correct console response should be:

```
GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1 304 -
```

Problem: edit is being added on path  /edit/css/main.css HTTP/1.1". All css files are being load correctly, the only url where is failing is in this because of the appended url I just mentioned.

What could the problem be?

Comment: You haven't shown how you're referencing that CSS in your template.

Comment: I already edited the question @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute path for your CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Right.  The browser is constructing the entire URL from the partial href, not GAE.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple